# Will Mavericks Server cache Yosemite updates?

Tags: macos, software-update, server.app

Will Mavericks server cache Yosemite updates?

I can't tell—is it possible to actually see the saved cache?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Caching service will cache updates for all possible versions of OS X on all possible Macs. You are unable to view the contents of the cache in a meaningful way though.